# Pygame Rect sorting algorithem

Tags: pygame

I need to write a program where the user can switch between rect positions.( rects position re-ordering rellevant for activating other functions that not rellevant for this question.)

My algorithm works good but I'm sure there are better ways in terms of logical structure, memory and runtime. Unfortunately I did not find it myself. I need to compare my solution with other solutions (for self-esteem and to continue with my project)

````
class small_rect():
    def __init__(self,y,color,text): 
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(200,100,250,50)
        self.rect.center = (250,y)
        self.text = font.render(text,True,(255,255,255))
        
    def draw(self,rect_func):
        text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center=(rect_func.center))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text, text_rect)

class big_rect():
    def __init__(self,y):  
        self.color = (25,25,25)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(180,80,260,70)
        self.rect.center = (250,y)

    def draw(self): 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,self.rect,4)
 
r1 = small_rect(100,(100,100,100),'TEXT1')
r2 = small_rect(200,(200,20,20),'TEXT2')
r3 = small_rect(300,(20,200,20),'TEXT3')
r4 = small_rect(400,(20,200,200),'TEXT4')

R1 = big_rect(100)
R2 = big_rect(200)
R3 = big_rect(300)
R4 = big_rect(400)


small_rect_lst = [r1,r2,r3,r4]
big_rect_lst = [R1,R2,R3,R4]

  
run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(fps)
    screen.fill((15,150,250))

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for i,rec in enumerate(small_rect_lst):
        if rec.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(250,250,250),rec.rect,4)
            
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] :
                rec.rect.centery = pos[1]
                
                if i > 0 and rec.rect.colliderect(big_rect_lst[i-1].rect):
                    small_rect_lst[i-1].rect.centery = big_rect_lst[i].rect.centery
                    rec.rect.centery = big_rect_lst[i-1].rect.centery
                    small_rect_lst[i-1],small_rect_lst[i] = small_rect_lst[i],small_rect_lst[i-1]

                if i < 3 and rec.rect.colliderect(big_rect_lst[i+1].rect):
                    small_rect_lst[i+1].rect.centery = big_rect_lst[i].rect.centery
                    rec.rect.centery = big_rect_lst[i+1].rect.centery
                    small_rect_lst[i+1],small_rect_lst[i] = small_rect_lst[i],small_rect_lst[i+1]
                    
            else:
                rec.rect.centery = big_rect_lst[i].rect.centery

        rec.draw(small_rect_lst[i].rect)

             
##    for j in big_rect_lst:
##        j.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```
````